# CountdownTimer won't tick even though wakelock was acquired

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

My app runs smoothly on the emulator - everything working exactly as it should - but not on my phone.

In my app, I use both a `countdownTimer` which ticks every minute, and an alarm manager, which should ensure that the user will be notified of whatever it needs to be notified of, should the phone be asleep.

Once the receiver receives the Alarm manager's broadcast, I acquire a partial wake lock for 5 seconds (which is even more than should be needed).

I checked, and `wakelock.isHeld()` returns `true`. I have the necessary permission, and the `onReceive` doesn't take *that* long (it is not at all computationally expensive).

And yet, the `countdownTimer` doesn't catch up. nothing else is fired until I actually unlock the phone and look at the app.

Any ideas why? I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

edit: Tried moving the wakelock (wl) declaration outside of the function (and even to the outer class), even though things worked as they were on the emulator (and from what I understand it shouldn't make a difference anyway, which it, indeed, did not :( )
code:

```
public class Class1 extends Binder {
    public static class Class1A extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp");
            //Acquire the lock
            wl.acquire(5 * 1000); //5 seconds to expiration
            // Do a few things
        }

    /// Some more code setting up the alarm
    }

    private class ReminderHandler extends CountDownTimer {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            logTxt.append("\nTicked. ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            GregorianCalendar tmp = new GregorianCalendar();
            logTxt.append("\nCountdown completed at "+ frmtr.format(tmp.getTime()));
        }

        public ReminderHandler(int Len)
        {
            super((((long) Len)*60*1000),60*999);

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

As I said, the alarm is received, I acquire a wakelock successfully, but the `onTick` doesn't happen until I actually unlock the phone and open the app.

Comment: What andoid api level do you use in your app?

Comment: on top of that show code sir

Comment: @dilix Compiling for API level 19. build tools 23.1.0 or higher if there was an update recently :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not an answer I am happy with, but for now, this is all I have:

It seems the it takes more than 5 seconds (and even more than the 15 seconds I later gave it to test this) for the CountdownTimer to catch up (even if it should have only had 1 `onTick` and 1 `onFinish` call to catch up to).

I simply released the wakelock in the `onFinish`. I don't like this (since if there is some bug, it could end up holding the wakelock for way too long), but for now, this is all I can do.